# Where can I find ubuntu-10.04.1-netbook-i386.iso?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook, live-cd

In the various download repositories, there are 10.04.1 ISO images of Ubuntu desktop, alternate and server editions, but I can only find the original ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso, not an updated ubuntu-10.04.1-netbook-i386.iso. Is the latter ISO available somewhere? If no, why doesn't the Ubuntu maintainers create one for this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no netbook iso for 10.04.1. For some reason, unlike the desktop and server editions, Ubuntu Netbook 10.04 is not considered a [Long Term Support (LTS)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) release. Though, all hope is not lost. If you install from the original ubuntu-10.04-netbook-i386.iso and apply all the updates, you will effectively have Ubuntu Netbook 10.04.1. If you look at [10.04.1's changelog](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/10.04.1), it includes many netbook fixes even though it is not a LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I found a mirror that has a copy of it here:

http://kambing.ui.ac.id/iso/ubuntu/releases/lucid/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download

My guess would be there is no 10.04.1 since an upgrade from CD or via Internet is available for the 10.10

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Netbook 10.04 is not an LTS version (LTS is only "classic" Ubuntu and Ubuntu server) -- so there are no maintaince updates (10.04.x) for netbook version.

(The same as with Kubuntu 8.04.)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Answer (score -1):

The official site will give you the newest, 10.10, or you can go here for 10.04.1 - http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

Comment: Sorry but i do not see a 10.04.1 for Netbook there. The only released version was the 10.04 for Netbooks. 10.04.1 for Netbooks is not available.